# Trigger page load blocking explicitly in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I understand that the top level webdriver API doesn't provide access to the page load event handler, but is there any way (including sending a command directly to the server through the REST interface) to make a call directly to the selenium server to force the page load block behavior?  I know about the wait for element hack, but I'd rather go straight to the source if at all possible.  The specific problem I'm having is a page that makes a JS call when a button is clicked that displays a modal dialog on the page while some backend processes happen, then forwards the browser to a new page once the backend work is complete.  Since the click action doesn't directly trigger the new page, selenium doesn't block on the event (and I wouldn't want it to in all cases anyway).

I've looked through the Command class for any promising looking commands, but didn't see anything.  I found http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol but it didn't help either...

Answer (score 1):

Thats a tricky one.

Accessing the http status in selenium/webdriver is not very handy.
I would recommend a pragmatic way. IMO the wait for element approach is not a hack, its the proper way to do it. In your case I would wait for selenium.getLocation() or webdriver.getCurrentUrl() contains an expected value.

Something like this:

```
webDriverWait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
    @Override
    public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
        //TODO: pass expected url as parameter
        boolean expectedUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl().contains("your redirect url");
        if (expectedUrl) {
            //If not null is returned, we have found something and waitUntil stops
            return new RemoteWebElement();
        }
        //try again
        return null;
    }
});
```

Comment: I can't use the wait module (at least without some serious modification for now) because I've actually jacked directly in to webdriver.execute to control page load events in my test framework, and I'd need to modify wait to be aware of the page load special cases as well.  I wrote my own wait method and attached it to webdriver (need to refactor it in to a proper subclass, but that's for later), and tried waiting for url change, but the problem is that just because the url is as expected doesn't mean the page is loaded and ready.  This becomes extra problematic when dealing with new windows.